# How can I get a language selector in top bar in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: keyboard-layout, gnome-shell, language-support, input-language

In Ubuntu 16.04 (which used the [Unity desktop)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10031/what-is-ubuntu-unity-for-the-desktop) I have a language selector in the top bar, next to the network icon and messages icon. Is there a way to have something similar in Ubuntu 19.04 (which uses the [GNOME desktop](https://www.gnome.org/))?  (Desktop [differences](https://www.lifewire.com/ubuntu-unity-vs-gnome-2201173) [more](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/05/ubuntu-18-04-the-return-of-a-familiar-interface-marks-the-best-ubuntu-in-years/))? I switch languages frequently, like when I want to type one word in Greek.

Comment: you can use **super/windows** +  **space** keys to switch between languages faster

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/configure-keyboard-ubuntu/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set up multiple input languages (keyboard layouts) first. The input language switcher icon would appear automatically in the top bar once you have two or more input languages.

Also as pointed out by [@singrium in comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174966/language-selector-in-top-bar-in-ubuntu-19-04#comment1961175_1174966), you can alternatively use the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> keyboard shortcut to switch between input languages.

Comment: where to find it? :) i tried to type " language" "keyboard" all leads to whole system re-localisation but not keyboard. i guess got used to 16.04 one

Comment: @ses https://askubuntu.com/a/929408/480481

Comment: And [a extension](https://github.com/ai/hide-keyboard-layout) to hide it