# Ubuntu layer set proper keyboard layer for german on Ubuntu 20 - bash terminal

Tags: command-line, keyboard-layout

Do you know the command to set the proper keyboard layer for german on Ubuntu 20 - bash terminal ?

```
qwertz
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change my keyboard layout in gnome shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41480/how-do-i-change-my-keyboard-layout-in-gnome-shell) Also, there is no such thing as Ubuntu 20. There is Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu 20.10 and Ubuntu core 20. the linked duplicate should work for the first two, provided you use Gnome (the default) as a desktop environment.

Comment: no @Bruni sorry, on bash terminal

Comment: I updated the question only over bash terminal