# How to undo Japanese character input mode?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, input-language

I accidentally hit my keyboard and pushed something and now whenever I type it's Japanese characters how do I undo it?

Comment: @DanielT well kinda, it lead me to the place where I can fix it, but only by removing all other languages. It says the button to switch is "layout default" so not sure what that means I pushed to get me there. but thanks!

Comment: If you don't have a Kana keyboard, you probably pushed Win+Space: https://askubuntu.com/a/1293985/1004020